# How can I make a non-handwriting text appearing like if someone writes it?

Tags: text-object, bevel, bezier-curves

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y59O7wunijo
 making a text with a Grease Pencil and then converting it to Bezier curve so I can control the text appearing by tweaking Bevel factor End parameter. However I need a printed text with fonts, I thought if I create a text and then convert it to Bezier Curve it would give me the same result, but it doesn`t work, nothing changes. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-an-svg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: text writing]

This is how I did it (this may not be the best solution).

Bevel factor works with non-cyclic curves. So you need to do this one character at a time.

- Create the text object of the character
- convert to curve (alt + c)
- uncheck cyclic (U) option in curve object data
- Extrude the unconnected node to have a closing edge manually
- increase depth to a non-zero value

Now you should be able to control the curve length with bevel factor.

Comment: Thanks! Slightly unusual method but works for sure! The only thing that bothers me though is the text has no body but the edges\contours, but for my particular project it`s totally fine

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

[image: draw text]
I could not resist the temptation of writing a script for this :) especially since the last segment could be difficult to replicate manually.

You might want to give it a try. Please be careful and backup your file before running it because the script deletes the original curve objects and replaces them with the new ones. Also it's not thoroughly tested.

```
import bpy

depth = 0.01

def createSpline(curveData, srcSpline):
    spline = curveData.splines.new('BEZIER')
    spline.bezier_points.add(len(srcSpline.bezier_points)-1)
    spline.use_cyclic_u = False

    for i in range(0, len(srcSpline.bezier_points)):
        spline.bezier_points[i].co = srcSpline.bezier_points[i].co
        spline.bezier_points[i].handle_left = srcSpline.bezier_points[i].handle_left
        spline.bezier_points[i].handle_left_type = srcSpline.bezier_points[i].handle_left_type
        spline.bezier_points[i].handle_right = srcSpline.bezier_points[i].handle_right
        spline.bezier_points[i].handle_right_type = srcSpline.bezier_points[i].handle_right_type

    if(srcSpline.use_cyclic_u == True):
        spline.bezier_points.add(1)
        spline.bezier_points[-1].co = srcSpline.bezier_points[0].co
        spline.bezier_points[-1].handle_left = srcSpline.bezier_points[0].handle_left
        spline.bezier_points[-1].handle_left_type = srcSpline.bezier_points[0].handle_left_type
        spline.bezier_points[-1].handle_right = srcSpline.bezier_points[0].handle_right
        spline.bezier_points[-1].handle_right_type = srcSpline.bezier_points[0].handle_right_type

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if(obj.type != 'CURVE'):
        continue

    curveData = obj.data
    if(len(curveData.splines) > 1 or curveData.splines[0].use_cyclic_u == True):
        for i, spline in enumerate(obj.data.splines):
            objCopy = obj.copy()
            dataCopy = obj.data.copy()
            dataCopy.splines.clear()
            dataCopy.bevel_depth = depth
            objCopy.data = dataCopy
            objCopy.name = obj.name+'_'+str(i)
            createSpline(dataCopy, spline)        
            bpy.context.scene.objects.link(objCopy)

        bpy.context.scene.objects.unlink(obj)
        bpy.data.curves.remove(curveData)
        bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
```

Comment: wow that`s smth new to me! I`ll definitely give it a try, never dealt with Text-like scripts, just opened up a console and pasted, every line is red and errors are everywhere. Will investigate further!

Comment: Sure. You will find instructions to execute a script in the second part of this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119694/61910