# Animate an object by moving it according to a list of coordinates

Tags: python, animation

I have the list of coordinates of an object (a ball) in 3d space in a csv file. How can I create an animation in blender of that ball moving through those coordinates?

Comment: Set the location of the ball with `ball.location = location_from_csv` followed by `ball.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', frame = frame_no)`

Comment: @BlenderDadaist I'm quite new to blender. Some context with the code might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have csv file with row like:

```
1.2,2.4,2.0
2.2,2.8,2.4
```

and assuming the requirement is to animate the ball with a constant frame interval between each of the coordinate set in csv, here is the code snippet:

```
import bpy
import csv
from mathutils import Vector

csvPath = '/path/to/the/csv'

#Not the most efficient way of creating a mesh , but should be fine for just one object
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=1)
ball = bpy.context.object

startFrame = 1
increment = 5 #This can also be in the csv
newFrame = startFrame

with open(csvPath) as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        #First set the location and then insert key frame
        ball.location = Vector([float(r) for r in row])
        ball.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', frame = newFrame)
        newFrame += increment

#Set the end of animation, if needed
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = newFrame
```

Comment: And how do I use it with blender. I'm getting a `module not found` error for `bpy` if I try to execute this code directly

Comment: Look at the second part of this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119694/61910

Answer (score 0):

```py
#Try this code:
import bpy
import csv
#Path to .csv on Windows style:
csvPath = 'C:\\test.csv'
'''
#test.scv example data:
0, 3, 2
4, 1, 6
1.2, 2.4, 2.7
2.5, 2.8, 2.4
1.2, 2.4, 1.9
'''
#Before executing the script create Sphere (Object Mode->Add->Mesh->UV Sphere)
#Basic data:
ob = bpy.data.objects["Sphere"]
start_pos = (0,0,0)
frame_num = 0
#Open the .csv file:
with open(csvPath, "r") as h_csv:
    h_csv_reader = csv.reader(h_csv)
    for row in h_csv_reader:   #cycle for row coordinate search in file
        positions = (float(row[0]), float(row[1]), float(row[2])) #animation x,y,z coordinates
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)
        ob.location = positions
        ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=-1)
        frame_num += 20
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the code and what it does