# How to position numbers on faces

Tags: edit-mode, faces, coordinates, axis

[image]

I want to position numbers on a die, and looking for an efficient technique to do that. My current approach is to copy Median XYZ of a face to coordinates of an object, can I do it in at once, instead of copying each separately?

Comment: For Location and Rotation in Object Mode you can use CTRL+ALT+C, unfortunately it doesn't work elsewhere. Even if you did, it probably wouldn't be what you expect; a face doesn't have coordinates on its own, this is why it's called a "Median", it's just an average of the coordinates of the vertices building a face. If you explain why you need this, we may rule out or confirm XY problem and figure out a workaround or better workflow…

Comment: Well, I'm making dices, and I put texts on faces as you see in the image. I need face's XYZ locations to put the text on the middle of the face. So I copy the XYZ locations of the face and paste them to the text's XYZ locations. Then the text becoming middle of the face.

Comment: Select the face in Edit mode, Shift-S > Cursor to Selected to move the 3D cursor to the centre of the face, Back in Object mode, you can then add your text and it will be added in the centre of the face. If the text already exists and you just want to move it to the face, use Shift-S > Selection to Cursor with the text selected.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Comment: Now added as an answer.

Comment: python solution here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/298457/142292

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the face in <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode, <kbd>Shift-S</kbd> > <kbd>Cursor to Selected</kbd> to move the 3D cursor to the centre of the face. Back in <kbd>Object</kbd> mode, you can then add your text and it will be added in the centre of the face. If the text already exists and you just want to move it to the face, select the text and use <kbd>Shift-S</kbd> > <kbd>Selection to Cursor</kbd> to move it to the centre of the face.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find a cool script by [batFinger](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger) on generating dices with numbers, but I found this instead:

[How to center text on slanted triangular face?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119694/60486)

### Manual

If you want to do it manually, You can consider a workflow like this:

[image]

In Edit Mode, the tool is switched to 3D cursor, and the orientation of it to geometry to align rotation with the normal. Then <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>$\color{green}{█}\color{#888}{0█}$ *left mouse button* is used to select a face, as John points out, <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to align the cursor to the center of the face, and in object mode, after duplicating the text, <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> again to align, this time selection to the cursor. Finally <kbd>F3</kbd> `Align Transform to Orientation`, to get that rotation correctly…

### Instancing

Select a big face, <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> Select Similar by area, <kbd>P</kbd> Separate by Selection, in Object mode hide the original object, set the text location and rotation to zeros, parent it with the newly created object, and set the latter's instancing to *Face* mode:

[image]

[image]

Then <kbd>F3</kbd> `Make Instances Real` and modify the texts, but I don't know why I get two text objects per face…

### Geometry Nodes

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice one +1. i have a [python solution here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/298457/142292) but now i realized that i could have just used the 3D cursor orientation thanks to your answer.