# How can I set the Z axis rotation of a text to face a face which is I selected?

Tags: edit-mode, faces, text-object, axis

[image]

[image]

As a dice builder, I want to set Z rotation axis of the text which you see in the image to the face which I selected. But how ?

Comment: Do you mean manually, or automatically? If automatically, how do you want to define 'up'?

Comment: The Z axis of the text will be facing towards the selected face. But orientation will be as "Normal".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rotate this manually, to eye, by setting orientation to local or normal and hitting r z to rotate in its Z axis.  Or, you can use constraints to orient the number automatically.

[image]

I've marked the top face, the one I want the numbers to track, by assigning its vertices to a vertex group.  Then I can use a locked track constraint on the text object to locked track the location of that vertex group-- with these settings, to rotate about its Z axis to point its Y axis at that location.

Since I'm using constraints anyways, I'm using a shrinkwrap constraint to place the text on the face to begin with.  You may have used snapping instead, which is fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily achieve this with a script which I have prepared at the bottom of this post. Select any face in *Edit Mode* and then click *Run Script*. It will automatically add a Text object to the center of the face that is aligned perfectly to the Normal of that selected face.

[image]

If you want to rotate or reposition the text object, just select the text object and press either <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad-7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad-7</kbd> (which correspond to *View > Align View > Align View to Active > Top/Bottom*) to get its Normal perfectly aligned to the camera. Then you can easily rotate or reposition the text while it's flat on the face.

[image]

Here's the Python script which you can paste into the [`Text Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html). It basically temporarily repositions the Z-Axis of the base object to face into the direction of the selected face normal and then positions the Cursor there and adds a text object. The text object is then aligned to face toward the same direction as the base object's Origin's z-axis.

```
import bpy

source_object = bpy.context.object
text = "A"

if bpy.context.active_object.mode != 'EDIT':
    raise RuntimeError("You must be in Edit Mode and have a selected face")

area_type = 'VIEW_3D'
areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]

if len(areas) <= 0:
    raise Exception(f"Make sure an Area of type {area_type} is open or visible in your screen!")

with bpy.context.temp_override(
    window=bpy.context.window,
    area=areas[0],
    regions=[region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0],
    screen=bpy.context.window.screen
):
    bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
    try:
        bpy.ops.transform.create_orientation(use=True)
    except:
        raise RuntimeError("You must select a face!")
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    transform_type = bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].type
    bpy.ops.transform.transform(mode='ALIGN', orient_type='Face', orient_matrix_type=transform_type, mirror=False, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False, snap=False, snap_elements={'INCREMENT'}, use_snap_project=False, snap_target='ACTIVE', use_snap_self=True, use_snap_edit=True, use_snap_nonedit=True, use_snap_selectable=False)
    bpy.ops.object.text_add(enter_editmode=False, align='CURSOR')
    text_object = bpy.context.active_object
    text_object.data.body = text
    text_object.data.extrude = 0.02
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center='MEDIAN')
    bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(use_offset=False)
    bpy.ops.transform.delete_orientation()
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_data_origin = False
    text_object.rotation_euler = source_object.rotation_euler.to_matrix().to_euler()
```